# How to create touch events for MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, touch, mkmapview

How to create Touch Events for MKMapView. 
I'm using UIViewController and adding MKMapView on that using interface builder.
Now I need to handle touch events for that map.....

I tried by writing UITouch Delegate methods 
But I failed...It is not getting called.

Please post a solution how to handle touch events on MKMapView.....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are happy with an iOS 4 and above solution, I've used UIGesture recognisers and never had a problem.

Here's an example for a long pressure gesture (tap and hold):

```
// Long press gesture recogniser
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                  initWithTarget:self 
                                                          action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];
```

And then you can handle the even in your `handleLongPressGesture:` method:

```
-(void)handleLongPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender 
{
     if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
          return;
     else {
         // Your app logic here...
     }
}
```